# На чём написать оконное приложение?

Tags: windows, uart

Есть большая потребность написать приложение под Винду, которое должно получать данные по UART (COM port), отображать их и отправлять обратно команды. Суть диагностическая утилита. Красиво не надо, надо функционально. Вопрос в следующем: какой язык для этого лучше подходит (знаю С, С++, Python) и какая среда разработки? Приложение не должно быть привязано к среде, как VisualBasic, должно открываться на всякой реликтовой технике и осях начиная с ХР

Comment: Странно слышать такой вопрос, от человека знающего С, С++, Python

Comment: Однозначно не ответишь. На чём умеете, на том и пишите. Однако Python-то в виндах привязан к своей "среде"

Comment: @MBo А C++ не привязан к архитектуре?

Comment: @Дмитрий Гвоздь C++ создаст исполняемый файл, который будет работать везде (если в свежей MSVS, например, предусмотреть совместимость с XP), а что со скриптом Py делать, если интерпретатор не установлен?

Comment: @MBo вау и конфликтов библиотек он никогда не вызывает да?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь странного особо ничего нет, просто практики нет оконных приложений. в консольку могу накодявкать, в окно не пробовал ни разу

Comment: Если речь идет о совместимости, начиная с XP, то может рассмотреть такой извратный вариант как WSH (Jscript) ? Правда работает он через объектную модель ActiveX.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего тут C++ без вариантов, если хочется использовать свежие версии компиляторов. Если бы не требование работы в Windows XP, то Python отлично подошел бы, но последняя версия, которая поддерживает Windows XP - Python 3.4.